# concurrent.futures: "A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending."

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

While using the Python 3.6 `concurrent` package, I am getting these on some processes errors seemingly randomly:

`Thread generated an exception: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

My dispatch code is as follows:

```
ks_par = []
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=pool_size) as executor:
    future_histogram = {executor.submit(process_event_thread, fname, ix, indices[ix], bn_arr): ix for ix in range(index, index + min(pool_size, remaining_events))}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_histogram):
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('Thread generated an exception: %s' % (exc))
        else:
            ks_par.append(data)
```

And my worker code is:

```
def process_event_thread(fname, ix, i_idx, bn_arr):
    with h5py.File(fname,'r') as f:
        f_idx = f['idx_tr'][ix]
        hit_pos = f['coord'][0,i_idx:f_idx,:]
        means = f['coord'][1,i_idx:f_idx,:]
        sigmas = f['sigma'][i_idx:f_idx]
        r_lens = f['r_lens'][()]
    n_ph = f_idx - i_idx
    i_idx = f_idx
    try:
        tr_dist, er_dist = ia.new_track_dist(hit_pos, means, sigmas, False, r_lens)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.info('Thread generated an exception: %s' % (ex))

    err_dist = 1./np.asarray(er_dist)
    hist = ia.make_hist(bn_arr, tr_dist, err_dist)
    return hist
```

(There are many methods in `ia` and supporting modules, so it is not practical to post all of it.  And a short test case does not fail.)

How can I debug this?

Comment: Probably the process killed is doing something that it shouldn't do. But there's no way of knowing **until you post the code** of your workers/`process_event_thread`. Btw, dict comprehension is not necessary in your code (you could use a list or set); but that's not causing the problems you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I posted the worker code, but it's not reasonable to post all of the code / files backing that.  Thanks for your help.